# Limit question: finding the limit as x tends to infinity of the quotient between a linear function and a non factorable quadratic funtion

Tags: limits

I know this one must be simple (it is from a high school book), but I am having trouble in finding the following limit.

$$\lim_{x\to +\infty } \frac{(1-x)}{(x^2+1)}$$

I already simplified the expression from the quotient between a third degree polynomial and a fourth degree one, but that was the farthest I managed to arrive.

Comment: Take $x^2$ common out of both numerator and denominator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HINT : Dividing top and bottom by $x^2$ gives you
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{1-x}{x^2+1}=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\frac{1}{x^2}-\frac{1}{x}}{1+\frac{1}{x^2}}$$

Answer (score 2):

**By l'hopital :**

$$...=\lim_{x\to\infty }\frac{-1}{2x}=0.$$

**By Taylor :**

$$...=\lim_{u\to 0}\frac{-u+u^2}{1+u^2}$$
and
$$\frac{-u+u^2}{1+u^2}=(-u+u^2)(1+o(1))=-u+o(u).$$

Therefore
$$\lim_{u\to\infty }\frac{-u+u^2}{1+u^2}=\lim_{u\to 0} -u+o(u)=0.$$

**Using comparaison :**

We can suppose that $x>1$ (because we want $x\to\infty $). And thus,
$$\underbrace{\frac{-x}{x^2}}_{=-\frac{1}{x}\to 0}\leq \frac{1-x}{x^2+1}\leq \underbrace{\frac{1}{1+x^2}}_{\to 0}$$

and thus $$\lim_{x\to\infty }\frac{1-x}{x^2+1}=0.$$

Answer (score 1):

By equivalents:
$$1-x\sim_{\infty} x, \quad x^2+1\sim_{\infty} x^2,\quad\text{so }\enspace\frac{1-x}{x^2+1}\sim_{\infty}-\frac x{x^2}=-\frac1x \to 0.$$

Anyway, it is a basic theorem that

*the limit of a rational function at infinity is the limit of the ratio of its highest degree terms.*

One cannot always reinvent the wheel…